# Firebase Test Lab fails when using ProGuard + Dagger

Tags: android, proguard, android-espresso, dagger-2, firebase-test-lab

Instrumented tests do pass on local emulators and physical devices but fail on Firebase Test Lab, when the following conditions are met:

- ProGuard is enabled for the debug builds;
- There are both Dagger and Espresso dependencies.

FTL shows different test issues:

1) In case with APIs 26-28 it shows either `Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'` or `Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'`

Exception stacktrace looks like this, it's not always shown in Firebase but is always present in logcat:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.dagger.internal.Factory>:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/inject/Provider;

FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Process: com.example.debug, PID: 11425
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/inject/Provider;
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:72)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:544)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:387)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.inject.Provider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.debug.test-9kvw--JgNKzmuQurRdDbCQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.debug-sz-oCUGs05zlEadCzyqsDA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.debug.test-9kvw--JgNKzmuQurRdDbCQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.debug-sz-oCUGs05zlEadCzyqsDA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 8 more
```

2) I also ran one test on API 21 which only had one NoClassDefFoundError in the logs. However, this exception is also present on APIs 26-28, but is a part of the exception shown above. Maybe there's just some difference between how it's logged on different API levels.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.dagger.internal.Factory

FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Process: com.example.debug, PID: 5691
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.dagger.internal.Factory
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

Some relevant lines from build.gradle configuration:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      minifyEnabled true
      useProguard true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
      testProguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0-beta01'
  androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta01') {
    //  exclude module: 'javax.inject' - Exclusion doesn't help
  }
  // androidTestImplementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1' - Inclusion doesn't help either
  androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta01') {
    exclude group: "org.junit"
  }
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta01'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0-beta01'
  androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.22.0'

  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
  kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
}
```

proguard-rules-test.pro:

```
-ignorewarnings
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
```

Upon disabling ProGuard or removing Dagger dependency, tests start to pass on FTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted Firebase support and got an embarrassingly simple solution.
Add the following rule to the proguard-rules-debug.pro

```
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
```

It's still not clear why this problem doesn't occur while testing locally.
But at least this solution works.